# Jenkins \ MultiJob can't run Multibranch jobs in parallel

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

was enjoyed multijob parallel. recently I converted most of my jobs to bo multi branch jobs. from that point multi job refuses to run them in parallel..anyone ever tried that? or maybe I'm missing something

Comment: please provide it in detail. if you have configured multijob in phases and the jobs inside the phases will be running in parellel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a known issue with the MultiJob plugin.  It cannot run Pipline jobs or derivate job types, like Multibranch Jobs.  See [JENKINS-31037](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31037)